# div click resize iframe or underlying div?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, click

i'm not getting a response on a div click just need to know what i'm doing wrong
http://jsfiddle.net/7nF2t/76/
thanks

```
<div id="click"><br></div>

$('#click').click(function(){
  alert('yes');
});
```

Comment: This is a JavaScript question (not the same thing as Java)—retagging.

Comment: `$('#click')` are you sure this is pure javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First if this is jQuery you have to use `.click` as many guys said.
AND #alpha isn't a CLASS it's an ID
i have changed your CSS, script, and HTML here:
http://jsfiddle.net/7nF2t/89/

```
<div id="alpha" class="alpha">
    <iframe id="iframe" src="http://time.is"></iframe>
</div>
<div id="click"><br></div>​

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#click').click(function(){
      alert('yes');
      $('#alpha').removeClass('alpha').addClass('alphas');
     });
});
</script>​

#click {
    z-index:2;
    margin-top:-200px;
    height:200px;
    width:200px;
    background-color:#888;
    opacity:0.48;
    filter:alpha(opacity=48);
}
.alpha {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
     -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
       -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 
          transition: all 0.3s ease-out; 

    -moz-transform:scale(0.25);
    -moz-transform-origin:0 0;
    -o-transform:scale(0.25);
    -o-transform-origin:0 0;
    -webkit-transform:scale(0.25);
    -webkit-transform-origin:0 0 
}

.alphas {
    opacity:0.38;
    filter:alpha(opacity=38);

    -webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
       -moz-transform: scale(1.5);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.5);
         -o-transform: scale(1.5);
            transform: scale(1.5);
}

​
```

Comment: how did you know alpha isn't an id? thanks btw [edit] oh the script function, of course! thanks!

Comment: sorry i didn't understand. anyway you can give style to an ID in CSS but it's still an ID and not a className. same as you give a style to any HTML element like body, or DIV etc..

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure the document is ready before adding your event, e.g. :

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#click').click(function() { alert('yes'); }
 });
```

Damnd, didn't see jsfiddle. xdazz is right.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.onclick` in your jsfiddle, use `.click` instead.

*[The demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/7nF2t/82/)*

Comment: thanks it's responding now; is it possible to transform on click?